# List of what classes are in what version of .Net (Win), Silverlight, Metro, and Mono (Mac OSX)

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, mono, microsoft-metro

I'm an independent developer coming from Java to .Net Desktop.  So I'm up against a learning curve and tend to think in terms of Java technologies.

Anyway I'm making a native desktop app for Windows (later you will buy it and we will all be happy!)  The app will be made with C# and WPF for the best user experience (very important).  While the priority is this best possible user experience I still want my code to be as portable as possible for future ports to other platforms.  Obviously the GUI parts will be platform specific but there is also a lot of database type code that could be cross platform.

So for a certain package in the Full desktop API (I guess you guys call it the "framework") is there a place I can get all this compatibility info?

Comment: With Silverlight you build web apps, but in Metro is not supported.

Comment: mono doesn't support WPF, so that will rule out MacOSX if you use WPF. Silverlight runs on Mac just fine, so if you need MacOSX support that's likely your best bet.

Comment: You misunderstood.  I know that I will have to program the GUI for Mac separately.  Please read the question.

Comment: You edited your question, I see...

Answer (score 3):

Each page of the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx) indicates which platforms and versions are supported. Just look at the **Version Information** section near the end of the page. For instance, it shows the following information for the [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

> **.NET Framework**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5
>   **.NET Framework Client Profile**
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>   **Portable Class Library**
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library

The information for Silverlight/Windows Phone is on a separate page, but if the type or member exists in Silverlight, you can access it from the **Other versions** dropdown at the top of the page.

Of course, it leaves Mono out, since Mono is not managed by Microsoft...

If you want to have maximum portability, you should probably have a look at the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find one site with all of this one it. Research is a giant part of development - you should be doing this on your own, rather than asking here. Google makes research easy - use it. Type "silverlight requirements" or "silverlight strengths vs weaknesses", etc.

You learn about technologies through research and use. There is no site out there that's just going to give you all the answers.

Comment: Who down-voted and why? If you're going to punish someone, man up and say why you did. Don't say I'm wrong and not explain why.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I disagree (at least partially) with this sentence: "You're not going to find one site with all of this one it". The MSDN documentation indicates the supported platform versions for each class and member. But of course there is not information about Mono...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque He was talking about Mono and OSX as well. He edited his question after I was down-voted; it was presented much differently, hence my answer. Before it almost sounded like he wanted his research done for him - which is why I told him to use Google. I get the sneaking suspicion he didn't like my answer, down-voted me and then changed his question. =)